# FIPS_mode_set function affects encryption

Tags: encryption, openssl, fips

To the best of my knowledge OpenSSL's function `FIPS_mode_set` should not affect encryption. All it does is terminating the program if a weak cipher is used.

I have a piece of code that uses `EVP_aes_128` encryption:

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;// = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_aes_128_cbc();
EVP_EncryptInit(&ctx, cipher, key, IV);
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding (&ctx, 0);
EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, encrypted.get(), &encrypted_size, paddedPlain.get(), encrypted_size);
return encrypted;
```

This code is consistent (I get the same output on every run) and working always as expected (decryption function is decrypting it back with no problems). But when I call `FIPS_mode_set`(1) on the beginning of the run, I get an inconsistent (different output on every run) output in the output buffer.

the input IV:
[image: IV file contents in HexEditor view]

the key file:
[image: key file contents in HexEditor view]

the input text:
[image: the input text]

the encryption output **without** 'FIPS_mode_set'(1):
[image: the encryption output without FIPS_mode_set]

the encryption output **with** 'FIPS_mode_set'(1):
[image: the encryption output with FIPS_mode_set]

I'm using OpenSSL version 1.0.2k.

What could possibly cause such behavior?

Comment: What do you mean with "inconsistent output"? Do you have an expected value (+ reasoning why you are expecting it) and the actual result? Please include it *into the question* if you do.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - I added some more information answering all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the API correctly, as you are forgetting to call `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()`. FIPS mode has more stringent requirements with regards to clearing buffers, so maybe that's why you don't get any ciphertext back before the call to `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` - which you don't seem to use.

---

Furthermore, you are using obsolete functions:

> The functions `EVP_EncryptInit()`, `EVP_EncryptFinal()`, `EVP_DecryptInit()`, `EVP_CipherInit()` and `EVP_CipherFinal()` are obsolete but are retained for compatibility with existing code. New code should use `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()`, `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()`, `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()`, `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex()`, `EVP_CipherInit_ex()` and `EVP_CipherFinal_ex()` because they can reuse an existing context without allocating and freeing it up on each call.

---

Please make sure you keep as much as possible to the examples in the [OpenSSL (EVP) Wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption).

Comment: I copied the code from the link, and only changed the cipher used (EVP_aes_128_cbc instead of EVP_aes_256_cbc). I figured out two things:
1. EVP_EncryptInit_ex fails which is why I'm getting garbage in the output
2. This is the output I'm getting:
'139693591844832:error:2D078072:lib(45):func(120):reason(114):fips.c:311:
139693591844832:error:2D06D073:lib(45):func(109):reason(115):fips_enc.c:124:'